# How can we reduce page fault

Tags: cpu-architecture

I learned that on virtual memory, the penalty caused by page fault is expensive. How do we reduce this page fault??I saw one argument that says a smaller page size reduces the page fault. Why is this true??

Answer (score 2):

To consider why smaller page sizes might reduce fault rates, consider and extreme example in the other direction.  Assume you have 2GB of physical memory and pages that are 1GB in size.  As soon as you allocate more than 2GB of virtual memory, you will have at least 3 pages, of which only 2 will fit in memory.  More than 1-in-3 memory accesses would cause a page fault.

Having smaller page sizes means you have more granularity, allowing the OS to perform more targeted swapping.

Of course (isn't it always that way), there are trade-offs.  For one, smaller page sizes means more pages, which means more overhead to manage pages.

One method to reduce page faults is to use a memory allocator that is smart about allocating memory likely to be used at the same time on the same pages.

For example, at the application level, bucket allocators ([example](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.genprogc/doc/genprogc/malloc_buckets.htm)) allow an application to request a chunk of memory that the application will then allocate from.  The application can use the bucket for specific phases of program execution and then release the bucket as a unit.  This helps to minimize memory fragmentation that might cause active and inactive parts of the program from receiving memory allocations from the same physical page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer..I get what you mean!! But is there any other way to reduce page fault other than smaller page size??

Comment: With a *simple* OS (that does not prefetch pages, at least under lower memory pressure) using *larger* pages can reduce the number of page faults by effectively prefetching what would be the adjacent page if page size was half as large. Page size also influences TLB performance--larger pages provide more TLB coverage for a given number of entries--, so optimizing page size is not obvious. An ISA might also not support much diversity in page sizes, simplifying the choice but preventing some optimization. (With hierarchical page tables, huge pages allow skipping a level, saving a small page.)